# how use [] attribute in object

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs

I build a query parser with Sequelize, I use [Op.or] instead '$or'

```
        case 'or': 
          where.[Op.or] = this._parseFilters(filterValue); // error: Parsing error: Identifier expected
          break;
        case 'and':
          where.[Op.and] = this._parseFilters(filterValue); // error: Parsing error: Identifier expected
          break;
```

How can add the attribute [Op.and] into 'where'?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `where[Op.or] = ...`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#objects_and_properties